# Homebrew always prompted fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git

Tags: homebrew

I'm using oh-my-zsh

```
➜  ~ brew -h  
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git

➜  ~ brew update
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git
```

How to fix this problem？

Comment: have you tried googling the error message? https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2883

Comment: I searched , but did not solve the problem, 
I looked at the address you provide , still does not solve my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a .git file under ~, which happens to be empty?

In my case, I cannot do git command under, say my/path,. I found an empty file in my/path, I deleted that file and everything works now.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the ~/.git, back to normal

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the already available .git file from that folder using terminal in case of debian based systems  .

```
sudo rm directoryname/.git/
```